# Data Validation custom formula list in Google Sheets

Tags: validation, if-statement, checkbox, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Is there a way to create a Data Validation list based on a conditional custom formula?

What I want is to put a data validation in B1 saying, if, column A1 = "`No`" then False, after that, I will select "Reject Input"

but if A1 = "`Yes`" then show me this list "`cat, dog, mouse, rat`"

I already have the first one figured out:

```
=if(A1="No",false,true)
```

But how do I add a command where if `=if(D6="handover",false,true)` is True, then show this dropdown list: "`cat, dog, mouse, rat`"

Answer (score 2):

## A1:

> [image: 1]

---

## B1:

> [image: 1]

---

## D1:D

> ```
> D1: cat
> D2: dog
> D3: mouse
> D4: rat
> ```
>
> [image: 1]

---

## E1:

> ```
> =IF(A1="YES", {D1:D}, "fail")
> ```
>
> [image: 1]